# Why does variable "not live long enough" when building a Vec of references from an existing Vec?

Tags: rust, vector

I am trying to implement an algorithm like below. I don't know how to make the local variable long enough. May be my design is fully wrong.

```
trait Metric {}
trait Update {}

struct Metric1 {}
impl Metric for Metric1 {}
impl Update for Metric1 {}

struct Metric2 {}
impl Metric for Metric2 {}
impl Update for Metric2 {}

struct Collector<'a> {
    metrics: Vec<&'a mut dyn Metric>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut vector_metrics: Vec<Box<dyn Metric>> = Vec::new();
    let mut vector_update: Vec<Box<dyn Update>> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..2 {
        if i == 0 {
            vector_metrics.push(Box::new(Metric1 {}));
            vector_update.push(Box::new(Metric1 {}));
        } else {
            vector_metrics.push(Box::new(Metric2 {}));
            vector_update.push(Box::new(Metric2 {}));
        }
    }

    let mut col_vector: Vec<&mut dyn Metric> = Vec::new();
    for mut met in vector_metrics {
        col_vector.push(&mut *met)
    }

    let _coll = Collector { metrics: col_vector };
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `*met` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:25
   |
30 |     for mut met in vector_metrics {
   |         ------- binding `met` declared here
31 |         col_vector.push(&mut *met)
   |         ----------      ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         |
   |         borrow later used here
32 |     }
   |     - `*met` dropped here while still borrowed
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9113bf70fe1511fc3ad8a9d5d9b523b3)

Comment: Please describe what is your goal, other than "I want to fix the error".

Answer (score 1):

`vector_metrics` owns the `Metric` objects it holds. And you are trying to create a new vector with a reference to those objects.

`for met in vector_metrics` moves each metric out of `vector_metrics` and into your `met` loop variable. Keeping a reference means there is no owner and the metric is dropped at the end of each loop iteration. To keep the metric owned you would need to store the owned value in `col_vector`:

```rust
    let mut col_vector : Vec<Box<dyn Metric>> = Vec::new();
    for met in vector_metrics{
        col_vector.push(met);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can iterate over `vector_metrics` non-destructively by taking a mutable reference to each element. This keeps ownership of the metrics in `vector_metrics`:

```rust
    let mut col_vector : Vec<& mut dyn Metric> = Vec::new();
    for met in &mut vector_metrics{
        col_vector.push(&mut **met);
    }
```